# Java- Print tree recursively with parenthesis

Tags: java, tree

*** I have answered my own question below ***

There are other great solutions as well in this thread.

*** Original Question: ***

I was trying print a tree which I constructed like so:

tree(root(20), tree(root(15), leaf(10), leaf(18)), tree(root(25), leaf(22), leaf(27)))

I have the following code:

```
static int childlev = 0;//This is global var used to keep track of parentheses

public static void printStruct(MyTree tree, int level) {//This prints out the data structure of the tree
    assert tree != null;
    if (tree instanceof MyLeaf) {//reached the bottom leaf
        MyLeaf leaf = (MyLeaf)tree;
        System.out.print(",leaf('" + leaf.value+ "':" + leaf.frequency + ")");
        childlev=level;

    } else if (tree instanceof MyNode) {//reached a parent
        if(childlev>level){//print parentheses when right child leaf is reached and level goes back to parent
            for(int i=0;i<childlev-level;i++)//child level minus parent level that we are backing up to
                System.out.print(")");
            childlev=0;
        }
        if(level!=0){
            System.out.print(",");
        }

        MyNode node = (MyNode)tree;
        System.out.print("tree(root("+node.frequency+")");
        // traverse left
        printStruct(node.left, level+1);

        // traverse right
        printStruct(node.right, level+1);
    }
}
//at the end of my main after calling above function i have this:
    for(int i=0; i<p; i++)//This puts in the final parentheses 
        System.out.print(")");
```

This outputs:

```
tree(root(170),tree(root(70),tree(root(32),tree(root(16),tree(root(8),leaf('x':4),tree(root(4),leaf('l':2),leaf('u':2),leaf('h':8),leaf('n':16)),tree(root(38),tree(root(17),leaf('w':8),leaf('o':9)),tree(root(21),tree(root(10),leaf('v':5),leaf('f':5)),tree(root(11),leaf('y':5),tree(root(6),leaf('g':3),leaf('a':3)))))),tree(root(100),tree(root(47),leaf('t':22),tree(root(25),tree(root(12),tree(root(6),leaf('c':3),tree(root(3),leaf('z':1),leaf('d':2),leaf('r':6),leaf('i':13))),tree(root(53),leaf('e':26),leaf('s':27))))
```

But as you can see, after leaf('u':2) there should be 2 parentheses but there isn't. So, right now if we have a right leaf followed by a right leaf we are not printing any closing parentheses. How do I fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `System.out.print(")");` after the last call to printStruct

Comment: @Ferrybig Sorry made some mistakes when I first posted it. I actually needed 2 parenthesis so it is a bit more difficult.

Comment: I think I have found a solution to my own problem. I am testing it right now. I will post it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't nearly as hard as you are making it.

First you should get rid of your `MyNode` and `MyLeaf` classes. You don't need them, and it makes updating the tree unnecessarily difficult. A node is a leaf is a tree. You only need `MyTree`, as follows:

```
public class MyTree
{
    private MyTree left;
    private MyTree right;
    private String value;
    private int frequency;
    // ... constructors etc

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.print("tree(");
        if (left != null || right != null)
        {
            System.out.print("root("+frequency);
            if (left != null)
            {
                System.out.print(",");
                left.print();
            }
            if (right != null)
            {
                System.out.print(",");
                right.print();
            }
            System.out.print(")"); // ends root()
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("leaf('"+value+"':"+frequency+")");
        }
        System.out.print(")"); // ends tree()
    }
```

If you really must retain the extra classes:

```
public abstract class MyTree
{
    // ...
    public abstract void print();
}

public class MyNode extends MyTree
{
    // ...
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.print("tree(");
        System.out.print("root("+this.frequency);
        if (left != null)
        {
            System.out.print(",");
            left.print();
        }
        if (right != null)
        {
            System.out.print(",");
            right.print();
        }
        System.out.print(")"); // ends root()
        System.out.print(")"); // ends tree()
    }
}

public class MyLeaf extends MyTree
{
    // ...

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.print("tree(");
        System.out.print("leaf('"+value+"':"+frequency+")");
        System.out.print(")"); // ends tree()
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need a bracket counter, and the method isn't static.

E&OE

Comment: Your code is brilliantly awesome! It helped me come up with a solution. Unfortunately, since other functions in my code depend on MyNode and MyLeaf I needed to make it work with them. I will post a link to my project on GitHub once I put it up. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @aahmed31 See edit. Your solution is still much more complex than required.

Comment: Thank you I will try this and post my outcome. Thank you so much!

Comment: When I tried your code the output does not have the right parentheses.

Answer (score -1):

*** I am answering my own question ***

My solution is a bit messy to say the least.

There are other great solutions in this thread but since my case is a little special I had to find my own way to do this. Basically fixing edge cases. I will give a link to my GitHub for this project, once it is up, so others may see it clearly.

Here is the working version:

```
//These are global vars declared up top
static int chl = 0;//keeps track of child level
static int retp = 0;//keeps track of return parent level
static int rl = 0;//keeps track of right leaves

//Here is the function to print out tree:
public static void printStruct(MyTree tree, int level, int right) {//This prints out the data structure of the tree
    assert tree != null;
    if (tree instanceof MyLeaf) {//reached the bottom leaf
        if(right==1 && rl>1){//print parentheses when right leaf is followed by right leaf
            for(int i=0;i<chl-retp;i++)
                System.out.print(")");
            retp--;
        }
        MyLeaf leaf = (MyLeaf)tree;
        System.out.print(",leaf('" + leaf.value+ "':" + leaf.frequency + ")");
        chl=level;
    } else if (tree instanceof MyNode) {//reached a parent
        rl=0;//next node is not leaf set back to zero
        if(chl>level){//print parentheses when right child leaf is reached and level goes back to ancestor parent
            for(int i=0;i<chl-level;i++)
                System.out.print(")");
            chl=0;
        }
        if(level!=0){//if not the first root then add comma
            System.out.print(",");
        }           
        MyNode node = (MyNode)tree;
        System.out.print("tree(root("+node.frequency+")");
        // traverse left
        if(node.left instanceof MyNode){
            retp=level;
        }
        printStruct(node.left, level+1, 0);

        // traverse right
        if(node.right instanceof MyNode){
            retp=level;
        }else rl++;//next node is right leaf
        printStruct(node.right, level+1, 1);
    }
}

//at the end of my main when calling above function I have this:
printStruct(tree, 0, 0);
for(int i=0; i<chl; i++)//This puts in the final parentheses 
    System.out.print(")");
```

Here is the correct output:

```
tree(root(170),tree(root(70),tree(root(32),tree(root(16),tree(root(8),leaf('x':4),tree(root(4),leaf('l':2),leaf('u':2))),leaf('h':8)),leaf('n':16)),tree(root(38),tree(root(17),leaf('w':8),leaf('o':9)),tree(root(21),tree(root(10),leaf('v':5),leaf('f':5)),tree(root(11),leaf('y':5),tree(root(6),leaf('g':3),leaf('a':3)))))),tree(root(100),tree(root(47),leaf('t':22),tree(root(25),tree(root(12),tree(root(6),leaf('c':3),tree(root(3),leaf('z':1),leaf('d':2))),leaf('r':6)),leaf('i':13))),tree(root(53),leaf('e':26),leaf('s':27))))
```

Comment: You don't need the counter or the loops. Just print one closing bracket after you recurse, as I did.

Comment: I'm downvoting this because it is really a poor solution.